# Why are using Promise in fetchdata?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```
function fetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = Math.random();
      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function pollData() {
  setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      const data = await fetchData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occured");
    }
  }, 5000);
}

pollData().catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error occurred", error);
});
```

Why do we need promise when the setTimeout is not a async function
(Just trying to understand short polling here)

Comment: Why do you think `setTimeout()` is not asynchronous? According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), it is.

Comment: It seems like the whole purpose of `fetchData` is to create a promise that resolves with a number after one second, so why _wouldn't_ you be using `Promise` there, whether or not `setTimeout` is synchronous?

Comment: Maybe what you mean is that `setTimeout()` doesn't return a promise like a function declared `async` does. That's the whole point -- since it doesn't return a promise itself, you have to wrap it in a promise so you can use `await`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need promise when the setTimeout is not a async function

That's exactly why the `Promise` is used here.  `setTimeout` is *asynchronous*, but it's not `async` in the sense that it doesn't return a `Promise`.  Wrapping it in a `Promise` and returning that is how one allows `setTimeout` to work like any other `Promise`.

Without it, the same functionality would require a callback:

```js
function fetchData(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const data = Math.random();
    callback(data);
  }, 1000);
}

async function pollData() {
  setInterval(() => {
    try {
      fetchData(data => console.log(data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occured");
    }
  }, 5000);
}

pollData().catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error occurred", error);
});
```

It's also worth noting that, while the `Promise` in `fetchData` *does* serve a purpose in your code, the `async` on `pollData` does not.  `pollData` itself doesn't do anything asynchronous, and the default `Promise` returned just by being an `async` function won't have any reason to reject.

Without the `Promise` in `fetchData` we also have no reason to wrap that `try/catch`.  That would likely be better done within the operation itself.

So we can further reduce and refactor the code:

```js
function fetchData(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      const data = Math.random();
      callback(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occured");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function pollData() {
  setInterval(() => {
    fetchData(data => console.log(data));
  }, 5000);
}

pollData();
```